# Cannot find object ID in database ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Express and every time I try updating a table - for example :

```
UPDATE Ulaz 
SET Stanje = 1 
WHERE (UlazId = 3)
```

I get an error

> Msg 592, Level 16, State 1, Procedure tr_dbo_Ulaz_57e9871d-3822-467b-a0a9-ff1b950b0d88_Sender, Line 45 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Cannot find object ID 98099390 in database ID 7

This happens for some tables but for some, it doesn't happen.

This started happening after the table has been updated a lot of times

Comment: Are you using sqltabledependency? Error and trigger naming convention look similar https://github.com/christiandelbianco/monitor-table-change-with-sqltabledependency/issues/188

Comment: I am using sqltabledependency

Comment: Looks like a known issue with that - and it appears to have been abandoned. You could look at https://github.com/tomasfabian/Joker/discussions/18

Comment: Hi did you find any solution for this problem?